# Fetch JSON via REST API using PHP cURL

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, spring-security

I want to retrieve a JSON data via REST API using PHP cURL.

Using the PHP code in this post, I was able to bypass the Spring Security page with the URL:

```
https://<host>/appserver/j_spring_security_check
```

However, the JSON exist inside this URL and I want to fetch it:

```
https://<host>/appserver/portal/api/1.0/apps
```

This is the PHP code I used to login automatically, I tried using `file_get_contents(url)` but it failed, only the below code worked to confirm login.

```php
<?php
function login(){
    $headers[]      = "Accept: */*";
    $headers[]      = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
    $headers[]      = "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    $data           = "j_username=admin&j_password=demoserver";
    $data           = rtrim($data, "&");
    global $sessionid;
    $sessionid      = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie2.txt'
    $ch                 = curl_init(); 
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_REFERER             => "https://<host>/appserver/portal/login",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => $headers,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE          => $sessionid,
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR           => $sessionid,
        CURLOPT_URL                 => "https://<host>/appserver/j_spring_security_check",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST      => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER      => false,
        CURLOPT_POST                => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $data,
        CURLOPT_HEADER              => true,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT           => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content            = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
login();
$text = file_get_contents($sessionid);
preg_match('/\w{32}/u', $text, $match);
$jsession = implode($match);

    $headers1[]         = "Accept: */*";
    $headers1[]         = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
    $headers1[]         = "Content-type: application/json";
    $headers1[]         = "Cookie: JSESSIONID=".$jsession;
$url = 'https://<host>/appserver/portal/api/1.0/apps';
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $sessionid);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $sessionid);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
// var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
$output = json_decode ( $result );
```

This is the result after execution of PHP code:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Fri, 17 Feb 2017 03:59:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_jk/1.2.37
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DB7139F7B8EE30F868A8392A4BF15523; Path=/appserver/; HttpOnly
Location: https://192.168.100.100:444/appserver/portal/welcome 
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

How can I fetch the JSON given the above cURL options?

Comment: When you say "result" you mean this is what you retrieve from `$result`?

Comment: Yes that was the output of $result in my code. I've just leveraged it from other sources..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting the cookie header manually when you already use cookiefile and cookiejar? That should not be needed.

It is also suspicious that you receive a setcookie header, probably the server is not accepting the session cookie you are sending.

Also, why are you not ignoring invalid SSL on the second request?

Finally, why are you not sending the same user-agent on the second request?

I guess that if you fix these problems you will see the expected behavior.

Comment: I'm not advising that, just helping to troubleshoot. Note that the first request works and the second does not. The first one is ignoring SSL, thus that is why I would suggest to try this. In the question you can read that he is running this on 192.168.100.100, which IMHO is not very likely to have a valid SSL certificate.

Comment: I got it to work after several tweaks. In order to get the JSESSIONID, you need something like CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION set to true. And since the old jsessionid is saved in cookie2.txt, I called it again as the id to the referer site.

Comment: Out of courtesy for the community please add your solution and accept it as the answer. Thank you.